# Specify Fortran module compile order with CMake

Tags: cmake, compilation, fortran

My Fortran project has a target comprised of a module containing helper functions and a few generated source files for tests. The test modules all use the helper module (i.e. `use test_tools`). I'm building with CMake, so the source list looks like

```
add_custom_command(
  # here's where I'm doing the stuff to generate test_SR#.F90
  GENERATED
)

set(SOURCES
  test_tools.F90
  test_SR1.F90   # contains `use test_tools`
  test_SR2.F90   # contains `use test_tools`
  ...
  test_SR20.F90  # contains `use test_tools`
)
```

This compiles fine on macOS and Linux, but on Windows with the Visual Studio 15 2017 generator `test_tools.F90` is not compiled before `test_SR#.F90` so on the first attempt the compile fails.

```
6> ... Done.  Results in C:/Users/rmudafor/Desktop/openfast453/build/unit_tests/tests/beamdyn/test_BD_CrvMatrixH.F90
6>Generating ../tests/beamdyn/test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90
6>Processing file C:/Users/rmudafor/Desktop/openfast453/unit_tests/../modules/beamdyn/tests/test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90
6> ... Done.  Results in C:/Users/rmudafor/Desktop/openfast453/build/unit_tests/tests/beamdyn/test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90
6>Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 19.1.1.216 [Intel(R) 64]...
6>test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90(19): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [TEST_TOOLS]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90(47): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [CALCROTATIONMATRIX]
6>compilation aborted for C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InputGlobalLocal.F90 (code 1)
6>test_BD_InitShpDerJaco.F90
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InitShpDerJaco.F90(9): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [TEST_TOOLS]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InitShpDerJaco.F90(54): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [SIMPLEPARAMETERTYPE]
6>compilation aborted for C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_InitShpDerJaco.F90 (code 1)
6>test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90(9): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [TEST_TOOLS]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90(32): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [SIMPLEPARAMETERTYPE]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90(33): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [SIMPLEMISCVARTYPE]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90(34): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [SIMPLEINPUTTYPE]
6>compilation aborted for C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_DistrLoadCopy.F90 (code 1)
6>test_BD_CrvCompose.F90
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_CrvCompose.F90(14): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [TEST_TOOLS]
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_CrvCompose.F90(48): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [CALCROTATIONMATRIX]
6>compilation aborted for C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_CrvCompose.F90 (code 1)
6>test_BD_GaussPointWeight.F90
6>C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_GaussPointWeight.F90(13): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [TEST_TOOLS]
6>compilation aborted for C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\tests\beamdyn\test_BD_GaussPointWeight.F90 (code 1)
6>test_tools.F90                        <---- HERE: this one should be compiled before the ones above
6>test_BD_diffmtc.F90
6>test_ExtractRelativeRotation.F90
6>test_BD_CrvMatrixH.F90
6>test_BD_QPData_mEta_rho.F90
6>test_BD_CrvMatrixR.F90
6>test_BD_GenerateGLL.F90
6>test_BD_CrvExtractCrv.F90
6>test_BD_GravityForce.F90
6>test_BD_CheckRotMat.F90
6>driver.F90
6>
6>Build log written to  "file://C:\Users\rmudafor\Desktop\openfast453\build\unit_tests\beamdyn\beamdyn_utest.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm"
6>beamdyn_utest - 16 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 5 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I let the build continue to the end, then `test_tools` will have been compiled and it will succeed the second time. This isn't an issue when I'm doing this manually, but it does prevent automating the build and test sequence.

I'd like to somehow indicate to CMake that it must compile `test_tools` before any of the `test_SR#.F90` modules.

I'm using CMake 3.17 on Windows, Visual Studio 15 2017, and Intel 2020 tools.

Comment: Can you post the full CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I started to add the CMake file above, but it really doesn't stand on its own very well since its part of a larger CMake project. Here's a link to the specific CMake file and you can see the rest of the CMake configuration: https://github.com/OpenFAST/openfast/blob/master/unit_tests/beamdyn/CMakeLists.txt#L32